# legend name too long for graph

Tags: r, bar-chart, legend

In a barplot, I'm trying to insert a legend that includes a long rowname, which gets cut off. How would I divide the rowname to take up 2 lines?

I'm aware that I could change the rowname too, but hoping there is another way.

```
    datab <- c(1,8.7, 19, 16, 13.2, 8.7, 67, 66)
    matrix.b <- matrix(datab, nrow=4, ncol=2, byrow=TRUE)
    colnames(matrix.b) <- c("Hazelnut", "Caneberry")
    rownames(matrix.b) <- c("Parasitism", "Predation", "Undeveloped wasp", 
    "Undamaged")
    par(mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 7.1), xpd=TRUE)
    barplot(matrix.b, col=heat.colors(length(rownames(matrix.b))), width=2, 
    cex=1.2, ylab="%", cex.axis=1.2, cex.lab=1.2)
    legend("topright",inset=c(-0.5,0), 
    fill=heat.colors(length(rownames(matrix.b))), legend=rownames(matrix.b))
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKJbw.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Increase plot margin

If you don't want to change the rownames you could either change the plot margins, or the position of the legend. As for the former, the following increases the right plot margin

```
par(mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 12), xpd=TRUE)
```

---

## Multiline legend entries

You could also split legend entries, and add a newline after every word

```
# Introduce newline (\n) between words
rownames(matrix.b) <- sapply(rownames(matrix.b), function(x) {
    words <- unlist(strsplit(x, " "));
    if (length(words) > 1) paste(words, collapse = "\n") else words;
})
# Plot
par(mar=c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 12), xpd=TRUE)
barplot(matrix.b, col=heat.colors(length(rownames(matrix.b))), width=2, cex=1.2, ylab="%", cex.axis=1.2, cex.lab=1.2)
legend("topright",inset=c(-0.5,0), fill=heat.colors(length(rownames(matrix.b))), legend=rownames(matrix.b))
```

[image]